# How much do I have to pay tax for selling stock?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax

Say for example I am Bill Gates and I have $10 Billion in my bank account. Then I decide to buy Tesla stock, at a current price of $1,000 per share.
Then, after 2 or more years, the share price is exactly the same and I sell all my shares and I get $10 Billion. In the meanwhile I got no dividends at all. This is not 401k stock, it is just the savings of an ultra-rich person.

There is no gain here so I guess the capital gain tax is zero. Do I have to pay any other tax for selling those shares? If yes then how much I have to pay? Or does the buyer have to pay a tax?

I am asking about the taxes in USA

In some countries, if you sell your house, the buyer has to pay a tax (say around 10%). Is there a similar tax for selling/buying shares?

Comment: "In my country" The question is tagged US - are you talking about some other country?

Comment: @DStanley - the question is for USA. I edited the question

Comment: Exercising a stock option does not incur a capital gain unless you *sell* the stock after exercising the option. (Exercising an option just means buying the stock at the price the option entitles you to pay, typically less than the current market price. The spread--the difference between your option price and the market price--is taxed as ordinary income.)

Comment: (And actually, I don't recall if you owe the income tax upon exercising stock, or only after you sell the stock.)

Comment: @chepner - your statement is contradictory. You said that it does not incur a capital gain and then you said it is taxed. Elon Musk had to sell stock and to pay a tax for the capital gain in order to be able to exercise stock options (54%) - https://www.cnbc.com/2021/11/07/elon-musk-faces-a-15-billion-tax-bill-which-is-likely-the-real-reason-hes-selling-stock.html

Comment: @JoeJobs There are two different taxes: the spread is taxed as income, while a capital gain (when incurred) is taxed as a capital gain. The rates can be different.

Comment: How's the story of elon musk related to your question?

Comment: @JoeJobs Elon Musk pays taxes on the discount, which is in essence his salary. It has nothing to do with owning shares or capital gains.

Comment: The answer to this would be no difference for a person having "only" $100K in his account. This has nothing to do with the tag ultra-rich.

Comment: @ApologisetoMonica - aren't the rich paying more taxes? I don't live in USA but I heard there are tax brackets

Comment: The text of the question also says nothing about stock options. What do Elon Musk's stock options have to do with the question that's being asked here?

Comment: @chepner - I am really sorry. It's very easy for a noob like me to confuse the income tax with the capital gain tax. If that's better I can delete my comment.

Comment: @joe jobs  - Capital Gains taxes are one kind of income taxes. And to your point about tax brackets, they don't matter in the context of your question where the capital gain is zero (you made no profit). 10% of $0 is the same as 50% of $0. If the stock had gone up in price someone with a high income that year might change how much tax is owed. Note: How much money they HAVE is irrelevant here too, only how much income they had in that year.

Comment: @JohnFx - Thanks. I apologize to all for my unfortunate comments. If there is anything I can do to improve the question please let me know (it has -2 votes atm)

Comment: @chepner - This makes no sense: *There are two different taxes: the spread is taxed as income, while a capital gain (when incurred) is taxed as a capital gain.*

Comment: @chepner - Not sure why you introduced exercising options into this when the question is simply about the taxes due on a capital gain of zero.  But given that you have done so, your comments are confusing because of your terminology, and contradictory.  Option price is the cost of the option.  Option strike price is the appropriate description for purchase price. The cost basis is the strike price plus anything paid for the call.  The gain is long or short term depending on the holding period (ordinary income versus LTCG).

Comment: @BobBaerker Because the question originally specifically asked about stock options before being edited to talk about buying stock in general.

Comment: That's the problem with significant changes after editing.  It's destroys the context of comments.

Answer (score 6):

In the US, there are a large variety of taxes for different contexts. There are property taxes, sales taxes, income taxes, inheritance taxes, cigarette taxes, gasoline taxes, etc.

With stocks and other related financial instruments (ETFs, LPs, derivatives, etc.) the only two taxes that occur in the vast majority of cases are capital gains taxes and dividend taxes. Capital gains taxes are levied when you sell a stock for more than you paid for it (and can be offset by capital losses), and dividend taxes are levied when you receive dividends (I'm ignoring the details of short/long-term capital gains and qualified/unqualified dividends).

There are no property taxes, sales taxes, or other types of taxes that you might find when selling a house or a car.

Also, you technically don't pay tax *when you sell*. You pay tax when you *file*. All of your capital gains and losses for the year are netted out, and you pay tax on the total net gain, or can deduct the total net loss (again ignoring short/long-term and deduction caps)

Comment: AFAIK you pay tax when you buy a car (VAT). When you buy a home in Germany, you'll need to pay transfer tax (Grunderwebsteur). This is levied from 3.5% of the purchase price. There is no tax for buying a house in USA?

Comment: Not in the US (and there is no VAT in the US - the closest analog is sales tax). In the US most states have a "property tax" that you pay annually based on the value of the house.

Comment: California (I don't know about other states) has a real estate transfer tax. But at 0.11% it's easy to forget about among the other fees involved in a real estate transaction. [source](https://www.chicagotitleconnection.com/Images2011/PDF/TransferTax.pdf). It may be paid by either the buyer or the seller, as specified in the sales contract.

Comment: @ThePhoton not "California", but "some localities in California". There's no state-wide transfer tax, only few municipalities impose it.

Comment: @littleadv, it's a county tax, but the rate is set by the state. Every county collects it (see the link in my previous comment). Some municipalities impose an additional transfer tax. also listed in the linked document.

Comment: Nit: for US you deduct net capital loss _up to $3k per year_ (half if MFS) with any excess carried forward to the following year(s). For mutual funds that realize cap gains on _their_ transactions, that amount must be distributed to you and is taxed when received (not when _you_ sell); ETFs may also do this but usually avoid it due to their redemption mechanism. For a partnership you are treated as receiving, and are taxed on, your share of the partnership's gains each year, whether or not you actually draw them.

Comment: Also you _may_ need to pay during the year: if you end up with sufficient net gain to produce substantial tax and you _didn't_ either increase withholding on other income (which you effectively pay during the year) or make estimated payments no later than the 'quarter'(s) in which the gain(s) occurred (also during the year) you may be subject to the underpayment penalty on form 2210.

Answer (score 3):

If you sell shares of stock for the exact same price as what you paid for those shares, then the capital gains is zero; thus the capital gains tax is also zero.

It gets more complex if during the time period that the shares were owned, the company paid dividends. That would mean that that those dividends were probably taxable. If the dividends were reinvested by buying mare shares those shares would have a separate basis, and selling those could trigger a capital gains taxes when they are sold.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the dividends. I edited the question now - no dividends at all

Comment: When selling/buying a house there is a tax for that, no matter if there is any capital gain for the house. There is no similar tax for selling shares?

Comment: There are no capital gains taxes on the sale of a personal residence owned for two years or more unless the gains are 250K for an individual of 500K for a couple. If it is an investment property, it gets much more complex because of depreciation and the recapture of that depreciation.

Comment: I was not asking specifically about capital gains tax. I was talking about tax in general. When I buy a house I have to pay a tax

Comment: There may be _other_ taxes that are paid when buying/selling a house (i.e. prepaying or getting refunded for property taxes) but capital gains isn't one of them outside of the scenario mhoran outlines.

Comment: Maybe I should ask a separate question for buying/selling house tax

Comment: @JoeJobs "When selling/buying a house there is a tax for that" I am not aware of any tax for this in the US.

Comment: @GlenYates, California (I don't know about other states) has a real estate transfer tax. But at 0.11% it's easy to forget about among the other fees involved in a real estate transaction. [source](https://therealestate24.com/california-real-estate-sales-tax/)